# how to solve getting 404 in Laravel 5.4 : Api route list

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I am getting 404 while am trying to access my api url here is my route :

MY Api route list:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('testapi','ApiDoctorController@testapi');
```

and the controller function that is provide data response is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiDoctorController extends Controller
{
public function testapi(){

$data = [
'name' => 'HEllo',
 'age' => '24',
 'height' => '5.4'
]

return response()->json($data);
}
}
```

When i try to access it in post-man at http://mydomain/project/api/testapi

its showing 404 error i am new to laravel help me out please

[![POSTMAN RESPONSE][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uV6Z.png

Comment: did you try `http://mydomain/api/testapi` ?

Comment: Is this route `Route::get('testapi','ApiDoctorController@testapi');  ` exist in the `routes/api.php` ?

Comment: thanks sohel i tried http://mydomain/project/api/testapi  here project is the directory where i install laravel

Comment: thanks maraboc yes it is in the routes/api.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your missing the semicolon on the end of your data array.

Is `Route::get('testapi','ApiDoctorController@testapi');` in your routes/api.php?

If not you'll need to define it so.

In postman you're doing `domain/project/api/testapi` when it should be `domain/api/testapi` as that is what you have specified in your routes file unless your entire laravel install is in `domain/project`.

I have added the semi-colon for you and formatted the code. If you're testing via postman please ensure that CSRF is disabled in your App/Http/Kernel.php (Just comment it out for your testing) then place it back in when you've setup authentication.

Let me know if this helps!

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiDoctorController extends Controller
{
  public function testapi()
  {
    $data = [
        'name' => 'Hello',
        'age' => '24',
        'height' => '5.4'
    ];

    return response()->json($data);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot mike i test it still got 404 and my whole laravel is installed in the directory /project/

Comment: as per your instruction i comment the field in kernel file

Comment: also i added the missing semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone i got it i just add public after my project directory and it work thanks to all of you for your valuable time

[image: Issue resolved after adding public]